# I have a long json that i want to be displayed only four when the page loads and shows the rest when a user clicks on the investment link

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a long json that i want to be displayed only four when the page loads and shows the rest when a user clicks on the investment link.

This is my investment table

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full-pagination table-responsive" id="investmentTable">
    <thead id="tableHead">
        <tr id="tableRow">
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 30%;" id="serialNo">S/N</th>
            <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;" id="investmentNo">Investment No</th>
            <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;" id="amount">Amount</th>
            <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;" id="status">Status</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>       
</table>
```

This is the Json test and code

```
// Call for Investment Api
function investmentData(){
   var myInvestment =  [
  { 
   "investmentNo":"00032", 
   "amount":"70000", 
   "status": "Expired",
   "duration": "2",
   "startDate": "7-02-2020",
   "yield": "2.60",
   "repayAmt":"70500",
   "description": "Official"

},
{
 "investmentNo":"00033",
 "amount":"40000",
 "status": "Current",
 "duration": "3",
 "startDate": "4-01-2019",
 "yield": "12.0",
 "repayAmt":"42000",
 "description": "Personal"

},

{
 "investmentNo":"00034",
 "amount":"5000",
 "status": "Current",
 "duration": "4",
 "startDate": "5-04-2008",
 "yield": "20.0",
 "repayAmt":"6000",
 "description": "School fees"

}
]  

var investmentTable = document.querySelector("#investmentTable");
        if(myInvestment.length>0){
var col = []; // define an empty array
            for (var i = 0; i < myInvestment.length; i++) {
                for (var key in myInvestment[i]) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }   

            // CREATE TABLE HEAD .
            var tHead = document.querySelector("#tableHead");                              
            // CREATE ROW FOR TABLE HEAD .
            var hRow = document.querySelector("#tableRow");                     
            // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.            
            tHead.appendChild(hRow);
            investmentTable.appendChild(tHead);            
            // CREATE TABLE BODY .
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");                
            // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
            for (var i = 0; i < myInvestment.length; i++) {            
                    var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
                    // CREATE ROW FOR EACH RECORD .
                        var td = document.createElement("td");
                        td.innerHTML = i+1;
                        bRow.appendChild(td);                    

                    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        var td = document.createElement("td");
                        if (j==0) {
                            td.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick = "return invModalView('+i+')">'+myInvestment[i][col[j]]+ '</a>';
                          bRow.appendChild(td);
                        }else{
                        td.innerHTML = myInvestment[i][col[j]];
                        bRow.appendChild(td);
                    }if (j==2) {
                        td.innerHTML = '<div class="badge">'+myInvestment[i][col[j]]+ '</div>';
                        if (td.textContent=="Expired") {
                            td.innerHTML = '<div class="badge badge-success">'+myInvestment[i][col[j]]+ '</div>';
                        } else {
                                  td.innerHTML = '<div class="badge badge-danger">'+myInvestment[i][col[j]]+ '</div>';
                            }
                    }
                    }
                    tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
            }
            investmentTable.appendChild(tBody);   


var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(x=0;x<link.length;x++){
    link[x].onclick = function invModalView(k){
        var href = this.getAttribute("href");
        var modal = document.getElementById("modal-block-normal");
        modal.style.display = "block";
        var investNo = document.getElementById("investNo");
        var investmentTableModal = document.querySelector("#investmentTableModal");


  if(myInvestment.length>0){
var col = []; // define an empty array
            for (var i = 0; i < myInvestment.length; i++) {
                for (var key in myInvestment[i]) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }                                   
            // CREATE TABLE BODY .
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");                
            // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
            for (var k = 3; k < 7; k++){
                var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
            for (var i = 0; i < myInvestment.length; i++) {                               
                    // CREATE ROW FOR EACH RECORD .
                   var td = document.createElement("td");                        
                       td.innerHTML = myInvestment[i][col[k]];
                        bRow.appendChild(td);                    
                    }
                    tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
            }
            investmentTableModal.appendChild(tBody);   
       }

    };
}
}
}

    **This is the modal table**
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter  table-responsive" id="investmentTableModal">
                        <thead id="tableHeadModal">


                                <tr>
                                       <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 40%;">Investment No</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                       <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 35%;">Duration</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                       <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 40%;">StartDate</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                       <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 40%;">Yield</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                       <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 40%;">RepaymentAmount</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                       <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 40%;">Description</th> 
                              </tr>


                           </thead>

                           </table>
```

The image is where the problem lies. it displays all values at once when i only want it to display the first array from index 3-7 in a row when a user clicks on the first link.

Comment: This is not JSON, but a JavaScript array of objects. This question should not be tagged as `json`. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: Why do you include the same image twice with about the same text below it?

Comment: Its an error please. i have been trying to remove one